# Jacobi/Gauss Seidel Methods in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I need to implement the Jacobi and Guass Seidel, methods in Matlab.

I found [this link](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/5235) which has code that produces correct results (on the one sample I tried) for each.

See post 3.

My problem is that the implementation is different to that described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method), and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method)

I'm happy enough using someone else's code (indeed I prefer something tried and tested) but I want to understand exactly how it works.

Can someone point me to a description of the implementations used in the post?

Alternately are there other implementations of these algortihms that might be considered benchmarks in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to show you how the code on Seidel works, hopefully you can do the same analysis on Jacobi yourself.

```
Q=tril(A); % Q == L
r=b-A*x;
dx=Q\r;
```

This part mathematically means `x(:,k+1) = inv(L) * (b - A*x(:,k)) = inv(L) * (b - L*x(:,k) - U*x(:,k));`

while in the wikipedia page you provides, it requires `inv(L) * (b - U*x(:,k));`

but they are equivalent since `inv(L) * (b - L*x(:,k) - U*x(:,k)) = inv(L) * (b - U*x(:,k)) - x(:,k);` so if you follow the formula in wikipedia, the iteration update should be: `x(:,k+1)=(dx + x(:,k));` while it is the same in the code you provided :`x(:,k+1) = x(:,k) + lambda * dx;`

Please note that lambda is a relaxation coefficient, mainly functions on the convergence speed adjuestment. You can set to `1` in the code, which makes it exactly the same as the formula in wikipeida.

Comment: Ah thanks that helps a lot! In the example you give though the x(y) is the same for L and U. But on the wikipeadia page L is multiplied by x(t+1). Does the derivation change when you allow for the updating of the x values applied to the L matrix?

Comment: @Bazman Thank you Bazman. See my update in answer for the label on x. The L is multiplied by x(t+1), but I used inverse of L to move it from the left part of equation to the right. thx