# Gauss-Seidel method doesn't work for large sparse arrays?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Once again I have a problem with the Gauss-Seidel Method in Matlab. Here it is:

```
function [x] = ex1_3(A,b)

format long 

sizeA=size(A,1);

x=zeros(sizeA,1);  

%Just a check for the conditions of the Gauss-Seidel Method (if it has dominant diagonal)

for i=1:sizeA
    sum=0;
    for j=1:sizeA
        if i~=j 
            sum=sum+abs(A(i,j));
        end
    end
    if abs(A(i,i))<sum
        fprintf('\nGauss-Seidel''s conditions not met!\n');
        return     
    end
end

%Actual Gauss-Seidel Method

max_temp=10^(-6); %Pass first iteration
while max_temp>(0.5*10^(-6))
    xprevious=x;
    for i=1:sizeA
        x(i,1)=b(i,1);
        for j=1:sizeA
            if i~=j
              x(i,1)=x(i,1)-A(i,j)*x(j,1); 
            end
        end
        x(i,1)=x(i,1)/A(i,i);
    end
    x
    %Calculating infinite norm of vector x-xprevious 

    temp=x-xprevious;
    max_temp=temp(1,1);
    for i=2:sizeA
       if abs(temp(i,1))>max_temp
           max_temp=abs(temp(i,1));
       end
    end
end
```

It actually works fine for a 100x100 matrix or smaller. However, my tutor wants it to work for 100000x100000 matrices. At first it was difficult to even create the matrix itself, but I managed to do it with a little help from here: 
[Matlab Help Center](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/accessing-sparse-matrices.html)

Now, I call the ex1_3 function with A as a parameter, but it goes really slow. Actually it never ends. How can I make it work?

Here's my code for creating the specific matrix my tutor wanted:
The important part is just that it meets these conditions: 
A(i; i) = 3, A(i - 1; i) = A(i; i + 1) = -1 n=100000

```
b=ones(100000,1);
b(1,1)=2;
b(100000,1)=2;

i=zeros(299998,1); %Matrix with the lines that we want to put nonzero elements 
j=zeros(299998,1);  %Matrix with the columns that we want to put nonzero elements 
s=zeros(299998,1); %Matrix with the nonzero elements. 
number=1; 
previousNumberJ=0;
numberJ=0;
for k=1:299998 %Our index in i and j matrices
    if mod((k-1),3)==0
        s(k,1)=3;
    else
        s(k,1)=-1;
    end
    if k==1 || k==2
        i(k,1)=1;
        j(k,1)=k;
    elseif k==299997 || k==299998   
        i(k,1)=100000;
        j(k,1)=(k-200000)+2;
    else
        if mod(k,3)==0
            number=number+1;
            numberJ=previousNumberJ+1;
            previousNumberJ=numberJ;
        end
        i(k,1)=number;
        j(k,1)=numberJ;
        numberJ=numberJ+1;
    end
end

A=sparse(i,j,s); %Creating the sparse array

x=ex1_3(A,b);
```

Comment: Your problem is that you are not using the sparsity of the matrix, your iteration also accesses all zero entries. You have to use the sparse encoding of A so that your matrix-vector multiplications only use the (nonzero) entries that are actually encoded in A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the for loop works very slowly in Matlab, perhaps you may want to try the [matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) of the iteration:

```
function x=gseidel(A,b)
    max_temp=10^(-6); %Pass first iteration
    x=b;
    Q=tril(A);
    r=b-A*x;

    for i=1:100
        dx=Q\r; 
        x=x+1*dx; 
        r=b-A*x; 

        % convergence check
       if all(abs(r)<max_temp) && all(abs(dx)<max_temp), return; end
    end
```

For your `A` and `b`, it only takes 16 steps to converge.

`tril` extracts the lower triangular part of `A`, you can also obtain this `Q` when you build up the matrix. Since `Q` is already the triangular matrix, you can [solve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_substitution) the equation `Q*dx=r` very easily if you are not allowed to use `\` function.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more, 'cause I'm new to Matlab, thus not used to it. Plus, I'm not allowed to use built-in functions (except for the basic ones like abs).

Comment: @Sofia I added the wikipedia page and some explanations. please see my update. thx

Comment: you dont need that variable. I deleted it . Thanks

Comment: I have two questions. :)
1. If x=x(k) and dx=x(k+1) why don't we just say x=dx instead of x=x+1*dx (which is actually the same as x=x+dx, isn't it?)? It doesn't work with x=dx obviously, but why?

Comment: 2. In the if statement what exactly are we checking? Because, normally I check if x(k+1)-x(k) (or dx-x here) is less that the wanted precision, but here it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance and sorry for all these questions!

Comment: @Sofia, (1) x=x+dx is actually x(k+1)=x(k)+dx, where dx is residue dependent orientation in your iteration, and r is the residue. (2)abs(dx) =abs(x(k+1)-x(k)), that is what you want to check. Normally you can only check one of them between dx and r, they are somehow equivalent. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I got the second one! ;) About the first one: 
In the wikipedia page you suggested there are some equations about x(k+1) (An example for the matrix version). Where's the dx factor there? Is your approach different from this one?

Comment: @Sofia please check out this page, they are equivalent indeed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829040/jacobi-gauss-seidel-methods-in-matlab/20829602#20829602

Comment: Thanks! It was my mistake! I re-checked it! You're amazing! :)